# Checking if a thread returned to thread pool

Tags: c#, multithreading, debugging, async-await

How can I check if a thread returned to the thread pool, using VS C# 2015 debugger?

What's problematic in my case is the fact that it cannot be detected by debugging line by line.

```
async Task foo()
{
    int y = 0;
    await Task.Delay(5);
    // (1) thread 2000 returns to thread pool here...
    while (y<5) y++;
}

async Task testAsync()
{
    Task task = foo();
    // (2) ... and here thread 2000 is back from the thread pool, to run the code below. I want
    // to confirm that it was in the thread pool in the meantime, using debugger.
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 100)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Async 1 before: " + i++);

    }
    await task;
}
```

In the first line of `testAsync` running on thread 2000, `foo` is called. Once it encounters `await Task.Delay(5)`, thread 2000 returns to thread pool (allegedly, I'm trying to confirm this), and the method waits for `Task.Delay(5)` to complete. In the meantime, the control returns to the caller and the first loop of `testAsync` is executed on thread 2000 as well.

So between two consecutive lines of code, the thread returned to thread pool and came back from there. How can I confirm this with debugger? Possibly with Threads debugger window?

To clarify a bit more what I'm asking: `foo` is running on thread 2000. There are two possible scenarios:

1. When it hits `await Task.Delay(5)`, thread 2000 returns to the thread pool for a very short time, and the control returns to the caller, at line (2), which will execute on thread 2000 taken from the thread pool. If this is true, you can't detect it easily, because Thread 2000 was in the thread pool during time **between two consecutive lines of code**.
2. When it hits `await Task.Delay(5)`, thread 2000 doesn't return to thread pool, but immediately executes code in `testAsync` starting from line (2)

I'd like to verify which one is really happening.

Comment: Try `await Task.Yield();` instead of `await Task.Delay(5);`.

Comment: @IvanStoev no difference. It doens't change the threads it runs on, or it doesn't behave in a different way in the threads debug window.

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a major mistake in your assumption:

> When it hits await Task.Delay(5), thread 2000 returns to the thread pool

Since you don't await `foo()` yet, when thread 2000 hits `Task.Delay(5)` it just creates a new `Task` and returns to `testAsync()` (to `int i = 0;`). It moves on to the `while` block, and only then you await `task`. At this point, if `task` is not completed yet, and assuming the rest of the code is awaited, thread 2000 will return to the thread pool. Otherwise, if `task` is already completed, it will synchronously continue from `foo()` (at `while (y<5) y++;`).

EDIT:

> what if the main method called testAsync?

When synchronous method calls and waits async method, it must block the thread if the async method returns uncompleted Task:

```
void Main()
{
    var task = foo();
    task.Wait(); //Will block the thread if foo() is not completed.
}
```

Note that in the above case the thread is not returning to the thread pool - it is completely suspended by the OS.

> Maybe you can give an example of how to call testAsync so that thread 2000 returns to the thread pool?

Assuming thread 2k is the main thread, it cannot return to the thread pool. But you can use `Task.Run(()=> foo())` to run `foo()` on the thread pool, and since the calling thread is the main thread, another thread pool thread will pick up that Task. So the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("main started on thread {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    var testAsyncTask = Task.Run(() => testAsync());
    testAsyncTask.Wait();
}
static async Task testAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("testAsync started on thread {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("testAsync continued on thread {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
}
```

Produced (on my PC) the following output:

```
main started on thread 1
testAsync started on thread 3
testAsync continued on thread 4
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Threads 3 and 4 came from and returned to the thread pool.

Comment: if task is not completed yet, and assuming the rest of the code is awaited - I thought that if the task is not completed yet, the control will return to the caller, on Thread 2000. If `testAsync` is awaited, then it will return yet another level up, on thread 2000 as well.

Comment: @user4205580 **"I thought that if the task is not completed yet, the control will return to the caller"** - it does! **"If testAsync is awaited, then it will return yet another level up"** - not exactly. When thread 2000 resumes to `testAsync` after it hits `await Task.Delay(5);` in `foo()`, it continues synchronous execution of `testAsync` until it need to `await` something. The first time `testAsync` awaits anything, it's after the `while` block.

Comment: Yes, and after it hits `await task`, it will return to the `callerOfTestAsync` and execute it on thread 2000, so thread 2000 doesn't return to thread pool. Well, I've just tested that.

Comment: As long as you understand that thread 2000 made a completely synchronous execution by that time :)

Comment: Thread 2000 had never returned to the thread pool by the time it hit `await task;`, and it was completely synchronous by then. A thread (in async program) will return to the thread pool only if all `await` operators up the stack are awaiting uncompleted Tasks. If it doesn't need to await anything, it continues synchronously.

Comment: But it's impossible for all methods up the stack to await uncompleted tasks. The last on in the chain, main method (at least in console app), is not async, so it cannot await anything and thread 2000 will execute the rest of main method, after the line `callerOfCallerOfCallerOf...CallerOfTestAsync()`, assuming that all other `callerOfCallerOfCallerOf...TestAsync` methods are awaiting in the chain.

Comment: Of course the main thread cannot return to the thread pool. In console application you must block on the Task in the `Main` method. In this case the thread is blocked by the OS if the task is not completed (rather than **"thread 2000 will execute the rest of main method"** which is not correct).

Comment: Or to make it simpler: what if the `main` method calls `testAsync`? Thread 2000 will first execute 'testAsync' until it encounters 'await task', then it will execute the rest of 'main' method and return to the thread pool. Thread 2000 is the main thread in this case.

Comment: Ok, now I'm lost. Maybe you can give an example of how to call `testAsync` so that thread 2000 returns to the thread pool?

Answer (score 3):

You can print out the `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` to the console. Note that the thread-pool is free to re-use that same thread to run continuations on it, so there's no guarantee that it'll be different:

```
void Main()
{
    TestAsync().Wait();
}

public async Task FooAsync()
{
    int y = 0;
    await Task.Delay(5);
    Console.WriteLine($"After awaiting in FooAsync:
                        {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId }");

    while (y < 5) y++;
}

public async Task TestAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Before awaiting in TestAsync:
        {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId }");
    Task task = foo();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 100)
    {
        var x = i++;
    }

    await task;
    Console.WriteLine($"After awaiting in TestAsync:
                        {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId }");
}
```

Another thing you can check is [`ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.getavailablethreads(v=vs.110).aspx) to determine if another worker has been handed out for use:

```
async Task FooAsync()
{
    int y = 0;
    await Task.Delay(5);

    Console.WriteLine("Thread-Pool threads after first await:");
    int avaliableWorkers;
    int avaliableIo;
    ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out avaliableWorkers, out avaliableIo);
    Console.WriteLine($"Available Workers: { avaliableWorkers}, 
                        Available IO: { avaliableIo }");

    while (y < 1000000000) y++;
}

async Task TestAsync()
{
    int avaliableWorkers;
    int avaliableIo;
    ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out avaliableWorkers, out avaliableIo);

    Console.WriteLine("Thread-Pool threads before first await:");
    Console.WriteLine($"Available Workers: { avaliableWorkers}, 
                        Available IO: { avaliableIo }");
    Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------");

    Task task = FooAsync();

    int i = 0;
    while (i < 100)
    {
        var x = i++;
    }

    await task;
}
```

On my machine, this yields:

```
Thread-Pool threads before first await:
Available Workers: 1023, Available IO: 1000
----------------------------------------------
Thread-Pool threads after first await:
Available Workers: 1022, Available IO: 1000
```

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing, and both Console.WriteLine print **the same thread ID** - because probably the thread 2000 first returned to the thread pool at `await Task.Delay(5)` and then was taken back from the thread pool to execute the first loop of `testAsync`. However, I want to check **if** the thread returned to the thread pool.

Comment: @user4205580 Why do you think it isn't returning? Where would that thread go? You have no way to iterate the threads inside the thread-pool, that is an implementation detail.

Comment: I've added comments to the code. I just want to know if it returns **to** the thread pool or not. It didn't have to return to thread pool, right? We don't know that.

Comment: @user4205580 I'm not following you. Where would they return to if not the thread-pool?

Comment: I know that if a thread returns, it retuns to the thead pool. I'm asking if it returns there for a very short time in this case, or just continues execution.

Comment: @user4205580 If the `Task` already completed, it will execute synchronously. You can check the managed thread id before and after `await Task.Delay(5)` for example.

Comment: @user4205580 See my edit, perhaps that'll help clarify more.

Comment: @user4205580 "I'm asking if it returns there for a very short time in this case, or just continues execution" - execution of **what**? If there are no pending work items in the pool's queue, what can it execute?

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to verify which one is really happening.

There is no way to "verify" that with debugger, because the debugger is made to simulate the logical (synchronous) flow - see [Walkthrough: Using the Debugger with Async Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155813.aspx).

In order to understand what is happening (FYI it's your case (2)), you need to learn how `await` works starting from [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) - **What Happens in an Async Method** section, [Control Flow in Async Programs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873191.aspx) and many other sources.

Look at this snippet:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // Initial thread pool thread
        var t = testAsync();
        t.Wait();
    });
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

If we make the lambda to be `async` and use `await t;` instead of `t.Wait();`, this is the point where the initial thread will be returned to the thread pool. As I mentioned above, you cannot verify that with debugger. But look at the above code and think logically - we are blocking the initial thread, so if it' wasn't free, your `testAsync` and `foo` methods will not be able to resume. But they do, and **this** can easily be verified by putting breakpoint **after** `await` lines.